# DDD for a marketing system

Tags: domain-driven-design

In Domain-Driven Design, how should we divide subdomains in the following system?
A marketing campaign management system, where every campaign has an initial target audience.
Each person within the target audience has dynamic attributes.
The campaign includes a set of filter conditions.
When a person's attributes in the target audience meet these conditions, the system assigns a task to them.
Once they complete the task, the system rewards them based on how they performed.
Initial target audience, filtering conditions, tasks, and rewards are all included within the definition of a marketing campaign, and they each have a fairly complex structure.

I have build several domains:

1. audience, CRUD;
2. filter, CRUD;
3. task, CRUD；
4. reward,CRUD；
   but how should we build the domain for the Campaign?
   One solution is to make Campaign domain depend on other domains. when we create the Campaign, other domain is called to create the corresponding instances.

one alternative is to  make  Campaign domain depend on nothing. Instead, we call other domains in the application layer.

the first method cause coupling between the domains; while the second method is hard to maintain as the business grows.